# assign value to a group pandas based on a day difference between them

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with ID and date ( and calculated day difference between the rows for the same ID)

```
ID  date    day_difference 
1   27/06/2019  0
1   28/06/2019  1
1   29/06/2019  1
1   01/07/2019  2
1   02/07/2019  1
1   03/07/2019  1
1   05/07/2019  2
2   27/06/2019  0
2   28/06/2019  1
2   29/06/2019  1
2   01/08/2019  33
2   02/08/2019  1
2   03/08/2019  1
2   04/08/2019  1
```

which i would like to group by ID and calculate  total duration  with a condition if day difference is bigger than 30 days re-use that ID again and create a new group starting counting duration from that day after a 30day gap.

Desired result

```
ID  Duration
1   8
2   3
2   4
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
(df.groupby(['ID', df.day_difference.gt(30).cumsum()])
   .agg(ID=('ID','first'), Duration=('ID','count'))
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Duration
0   1         7
1   2         3
2   2         4
```